# Chaining vs creating a new Collection - efficiency

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a beginner in Backbone and want to know which among the 2 is more efficient and the expected way of doing things.

**Type A** : Creating a new collection which accepts result from earlier operation and plucking a key from the new collection

```
result = new Backbone.Collection(this.collection.where({"x":y})).pluck("z")
```

OR

**Type B** : Chaining feature of collections - Array from filter and map.

```
result = this.collection.chain()
        .filter(function(model){model.get("x")===y)
        .map(function(model){model.get("z")})
        .value()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmarking is the key : chaining wins hands down<sup>1</sup> and is clearer<sup>2</sup>.
See http://jsperf.com/backbone-chaining-vs-new-collection for the comparison<sup>3</sup>.

Of course, if you're really concerned with speed, you would ditch the middle men and use vanilla JavaScript (this could be further optimized, look up array traversing techniques)

```
var i, l, result = [];
for (i=0, l=this.collection.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (this.collection.models[i].get('x') === y)
        result.push(this.collection.models[i].get('z'));
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Subject to your exact setup/data sample/speed of the wind
<sup>2</sup> Note that your `filter` and `map` functions miss a `return`
<sup>3</sup> Tests used : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cek502wp/